# What do square brackets without semicolons mean?

Tags: f#

I found the code below in the book `F# Design Patterns` by Gene Belitski. I have been reading about F# but I have not found an explanation for this syntax either on that book or elsewhere. I understand the keyword `yield` and what it does and I know that both the yield and printfn statements return values are of type unit. What I do not understand is the square brackets. The statements are not separated by semicolons as they would in a literal list creation. This must be a special syntax but I cannot find references to it. Can someone help?

```
let eagerList = [
    printfn "Evaluating eagerList"
    yield "I"
    yield "am"
    yield "an"
    yield "eager"
    yield "list" ]
```

Comment: I would assume this would be for a "generator", which is a function that returns an iterable (or some equivalent in F# that returns these values in "sequence". Every "yield" statement would require that you call theIterator.next ( ). So in order to see the whole sentence, you'd have to call "eagerList.next( )" a few times. Generators and "yield" are new to javascript, so I've never seen this syntax, but I'd imagine it's the same idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually a list comprehension or some sort of computation expression.  I think that example conflates a few different things which probably baffles you, so maybe that book is actually not the best first or intro book to F#. If you read p. 169 carefully it explains what it is all about though. Author wants to demonstrate that with `Seq.delay`, well, you can delay the eager evaluation. If you evaluate the list first it actually prints the "Evaluating eager list" part, but only when you create it. After that it won't. You can see that `printfn` is not part of the list. So it's more like a statement, one printfn, and an expression (string list) combined.

1. List syntax

Usually you will just generate a list, and not type it in but you can separate the items with a newline or a `;`. So these two lists are equivalent:

```
["a";"b";"c"]

["a"
 "b"
 "c"
]
```

2. Lists are always eager in F#, however seqs are lazy.
3. `yield` is sort of like `return` in C#, it doesn't return unit, it returns a value, especially in a sequence.

When you create the example you will get this:

> Evaluating eagerList
>   val eagerList : string list = ["I"; "am"; "an";
>   "eager"; "list"]

So you can see the `printfn` is not part of the list.

If you run `eagerList` you will only see:

> val it : string list = ["I"; "am"; "an"; "eager"; "list"]

Confirming our suspicion.

Now what Gene Belinitsky wanted to demonstrate is this:

```
let delayed = Seq.delay (fun _ ->  ([
                                        printfn "Evaluating eagerList"
                                        yield "I"
                                        yield "am"
                                        yield "an"
                                        yield "eager"
                                        yield "list" ] |> Seq.ofList))
```

> val delayed : seq

Not only it doesn't print out the list, it doesn't event prints the printfn statement! And it's a seq, not a list.

If you do `delayed` or `delayed   |> Seq.toList` each time you will get back the result from the printfn statement as well as the string list:

> Evaluating eagerList
>   val it : string list = ["I"; "am"; "an"; "eager";
>   "list"]

So to summarize it, yes, usually within [] you have a list and you either separate the itenms with a `;` or a newline. However that specific example is not actually a usual list but an expression designed to demonstrate how you can delay evaluation, and for that it contains a print statement as well as a string list.

Also `;` can be used to separate statements on the same line, e.g.
`printfn "%A" "foo";printfn "%A" "bar"`

Comment: I have the Kindle edition and it does not have the concept of a "page". If you can please let me know how can I find what is on p. 169.

Comment: @Soldalma Search for this heading: "The Collection Wrapping Pattern", the paragraphs right before and right after the `eagerList` example are relevant here.

Comment: It looks to me like it is indeed a list comprehension, not a list. Actually, the author says "there is an eager list comprehension ..." Also, all elements in a list must have the same type and I don't know how would that work with the `printfn` statement that has return type `unit` and the `yield` statements. Still, I have not seen the documentation for this type of list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

It is a list.

> You can define a list by explicitly listing out the elements, separated by semicolons and enclosed in square brackets.

```
 let eagerList = [ printfn "Evaluating eagerList"; yield "I"; yield "am"; yield "an"; yield "eager"; yield "list" ]
```

> You can also put line breaks between elements, in which case the semicolons are optional. The latter syntax can result in more readable code when the element initialization expressions are longer, or when you want to include a comment for each element.

```
let eagerList = [
    printfn "Evaluating eagerList"
    yield "I"
    yield "am"
    yield "an"
    yield "eager"
    yield "list" ]
```

Both of these codes do exactly the same.
**Note**, that the second snippet could have also been written like this, as the semicolons are optional if you put line breaks between elements.

```
let eagerList = [
    printfn "Evaluating eagerList";
    yield "I";
    yield "am";
    yield "an";
    yield "eager";
    yield "list"; ]
```

Check out [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/lists)

Comment: it's more like a list comprehension actually. Evaluate it twice and see why.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/lists), it is another syntax for defining lists.

Comment: You are not incorrect there :-). You can certainly skip the `;` when defying the list however the point of that example is quite diferent. Let me summarize in an answer. You can see the printfn is not part of the list, which it should be.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I wrote that the semicolons are optional anyway. Or do you mean the code snippet, where all that is written in a single line? :)